# How to make same Python version in cmd & Anaconda prompt

Tags: python, terminal, anaconda, version, interpreter

I'm a newbie programmer (little know about computer science BUT Love programming) using windows and have some problems with Python and VS Code in Anaconda. I have *v. 3.8.2* as I run python in *cmd* and *v.3.7.4* as I do that in *VS Code Terminal (lunched from Anaconda) or in Anaconda prompt*. My question is: How I can install the last version of python which becomes the interpreter of both my OS and VS Code in Anaconda? Do I need to uninstall any of them? **Thanks a LOT**

Answer (score 1):

You need to update them separately.

You can launch Anaconda prompt and type : conda update python
It should by default update the python version in anaconda
Or you can try
To update anaconda type :conda update anaconda
To download Python 3.9 (from Anaconda Prompt)
conda create -c conda-forge python=3.9 -n py39-demo

To update python on your pc go to https://www.python.org/ and download the latest version
However end note for updating python in Anaconda use the top method